# Loading chunk failed problem in only 1 PC from 1 URL

Tags: angular, windows, ionic-framework, ionic3, registry

I am getting loading chunk failed on Windows 10 PC when I am running my Ionic build from my hosting server. Except this PC, my application is used by more than 20 users from other computers as well, but error is coming only in 1 PC.

I notice some other advertisement page opens when I load my app URL, in another tab advertisement also opens.

Using Ionic 3 and lazy loading for the build.

Diagnosis shows:

1. when I copied the same build in local Xampp, it worked
2. When I copied the same build on another server it worked from there as well

URL 1 - apps.mydomain.com [pointed to server1] is giving error, but apps2.mydomain.com [pointed to server2] is working. Both have same builds.

I tried this on Chrome, Firefox same problem in both browsers. Seems it is not related to browser. Reinstalled browsers, did not worked.

No Chrome extensions installed, no external app found installed in control panel of Windows.

From where can I stop this unusual browser behavior of advertisement opening in this PC?

Comment: I'm afraid that it's hard to correctly "guess" the problem without a MCVE.

Comment: This question is lacking a [mcve] and thus should be put on hold for now. It can be reopened if it is suitably edited.